# How do you pass a Matrix or Playa field to a Stash Embed?

Tags: matrix, stash, embeds

This should be easy, but, I haven't been able to find an example anywhere.

I need to display {example_matrix_a} and {example_matrix_b} (both of which contain columns with the same names) via a Stash embed. I've tried the following, but, the Matrix fields aren't parsing. What step am I missing?

**templates/default_site/example.group/layout_example.html:**

```
{embed="wrappers/_interior"}

{exp:channel:entries limit="1"}
    {exp:stash:set name='title'}{title}{/exp:stash:set}
    {exp:stash:set name='maincontent'}
      {stash:embed:matrix_markup
        stash:matrix_field = "{example_matrix_a}"
        process="start"
      }
      {stash:embed:matrix_markup
        stash:matrix_field = "{example_matrix_b}"
        process="start"
      }

  {/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**stash_templates/matrix_markup.html**

```
{stash:matrix_field} 
   {matrix_col_1} - {matrix_col_2}<br>
{/stash:matrix_field}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution, per suggestions via Twitter by Stash's author:

**templates/default_site/example.group/layout_example.html:**

```
{embed="wrappers/_interior"}

{exp:channel:entries limit="1"}
    {exp:stash:set name='title'}{title}{/exp:stash:set}
    {exp:stash:set name='maincontent'}
      {stash:embed:matrix_markup
        stash:matrix_field = "example_matrix_a"
        process="start"
      }
      {stash:embed:matrix_markup
        stash:matrix_field = "example_matrix_b"
        process="start"
      }

  {/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**stash_templates/matrix_markup.html**

```
{{stash:matrix_field}} 
   {matrix_col_1} - {matrix_col_2}<br>
{/{stash:matrix_field}}
```

This method (passing the name of the variable) works with Playa as well, and, I'd guess with just about any other field type that uses tag pairs.

Comment: Nice. Glad he got you hooked up.

Answer (score 1):

First, check this out: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aset_list%7D#capturing-and-caching-playa--matrix-tag-pairs

Second, unless you're reusing the **matrix_markup** Stash template, just keep it all together.

**templates/default_site/example.group/layout_example.html:**

```
{exp:channel:entries ...}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="matrix_a" parse_tags="yes" save="yes" scope="site"}
        {example_matrix_a}
            {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
            {!-- new stash tags for your columns --}
        {/example_matrix_a}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}

    {exp:stash:set name="title"}{title}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

---

If, however, you are reusing the **matrix_markup** template, then you can do this.

**templates/default_site/example.group/layout_example.html:**

```
{exp:channel:entries ...}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="matrix_a" parse_tags="yes" save="yes" scope="site"}
        {stash:embed:partials:matrix_markup process="both"} {!-- or process="end" --}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}

    {exp:stash:set name="title"}{title}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**stash_templates/partials/matrix_markup.html** ← NOTE THE ADDITION OF THE 'PARTIALS' DIRECTORY

```
{example_matrix_a}
  {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
  {!-- new stash tags for your columns --}
{/example_matrix_a}
```

The Stash embed is assuming you have your config setup properly.